# Cron Expression not working correctly

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I've .net windows service which schedules Quartz jobs, I've the following code to start my job at 4 AM every day and repeat every 12 hours. Start time below will be different for each job. The problem here is it is not starting at 4 AM when I say, but it is only running at 12 AM and 12 PM every day. How can I ensure that it starts exactly at the time that I asked it to StartAtTime? If I reduce the value in my cron expression to either 1/2 and change the start time to some 2 PM or 3 PM whatever, it works as expected.

```
var startAtTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(localTime[Key]);

if (startAtTime.ToUniversalTime() < DateTime.UtcNow)
{
    startAtTime = startAtTime.AddDays(1);
}

ITrigger objESLJobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                           .WithIdentity("ESLTrigger-",             AuditType.ESL.ToString())
                           .StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(startAtTime))
                           .WithCronSchedule("0 0 0/12 ? * SUN-SAT", x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires())
                           .Build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as should. See

- `.StartAt()` method defines when start the trigger, not job.
- and your cron expression `0 0 0/12 ? * SUN-SAT` means exactly "*run job at at 12 AM and 12 PM every day*" (you may use [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com) to check).

Cron Scheduler is not helpful in your case, as it works with intervals in [different way](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html) that you expect:

> / - used to specify increments. For example, “0/15” in the seconds field means “the seconds 0, 15, 30, and 45”. And “5/15” in the seconds field means “the seconds 5, 20, 35, and 50”. You can also specify ‘/’ after the ‘’ character - in this case ‘’ is equivalent to having ‘0’ before the ‘/’. ‘1/3’ in the day-of-month field means “fire every 3 days starting on the first day of the month”.

So expression like `0 0 4/12 ? * SUN-SAT` will run every 12 hours at 4AM and 4PM. And `0 0 5/12 ? * SUN-SAT` will run every 12 hours at 5AM and 5PM. And StartAt() method only define when first job will be triggered (at 4AM or 4PM), it does not do offset for cron expression.

Just use SimpleSchedule instead:

```
ITrigger objESLJobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                           .WithIdentity("ESLTrigger-", AuditType.ESL.ToString())
                           .StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(startAtTime))
                           .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                               .WithIntervalInHours(12)
                               .RepeatForever())
                           .Build();
```

Comment: I don't want to use the simple trigger because I feel like it is less flexible than the cron in scheduling. What is the difference between the start trigger and start job, trigger executes the job right. As I said in my  questions if I say startAt at 13 HRS and repeat for every 2 hours it works, it starts exactly at 13 hrs and then repeat for every 2 hours.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth have updated answer. You may dynamically generate cron expression based on current (start) time.

Comment: thanks for your response, but my worry is that if I want to run the job say for every 30 minutes or every 2:30 hours based starting at specific time say 4 AM (this time is variable) I will not be able to do that with a simple trigger. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @AjaySrikanth just change WithIntervalInHours to WithIntervalInMinutes(30) or WithIntervalInMinutes(150) respectively

Comment: Thanks @set, I'll try this with StartAt, that is also. I really appreciate your help.